# Localhost-only RMI?

Tags: java, ipc, localhost, rmi, firewall

I have a project which starts a second JVM. Currently I'm using RMI to communicate between the two. Works well on my own machines.

I need to be able to deploy this project on Windows 7 machines where I do not have privileges to change firewall rules.

The registry (launched from within the first JVM on a high arbitrary port) is being blocked from opening a server socket on these machines.

Is there a way to restrict RMI to only listen to local connections; such that Windows firewall will be cool with it?

Alternatively, is there a good alternative IPC approach that will require little functional changes?

Cheers.

Comment: That's the very reason why web services (working on 8080 port) have gained popularity.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would help? I could open a local http connection between the two, but at that stage I'd be better off just running an object stream over sockets surely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is trickier than it appears to be at first. What is wanted is to restrict the IP *addresses* that the registry is listening on, but not the port. The problem is that the RMI Registry implementation program (`rmiregistry`) does not in fact provide any mechanism to restrict what IP addresses it listens on; it always listens on every network interface available. There are only two practical mechanisms for restricting this:

1. Use a firewall rule. This is the normal technique to be honest, but it requires configuration during deployment.
2. Use a special version of the RMI Registry that applies the restriction to just the right IP address (namely `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`) because Windows *doesn't* complain about sockets that can only be reached from the local machine.

This second option is what I'll sketch out. It's actually quite simple to do, since you can delegate most of the complexity to existing classes.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;

public class RestrictedRMIRegistry implements RMIServerSocketFactory {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        int port = (args.length == 0 ? 1099 : Integer.parseInt(args[0], 10));
        RMIClientSocketFactory csf = RMISocketFactory.getDefaultSocketFactory();
        RMIServerSocketFactory ssf = new RestrictedRMIRegistry();

        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port, csf, ssf);
    }

    public ServerSocket createServerSocket(int port) throws IOException {
        // Tricky bit; make a server socket with bound address
        return new ServerSocket(port, 0, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
    }
}
```

The only difference between this and the normal `rmiregistry` implementation is that that uses the defaults for *both* the client and server socket factories.

Comment: I found this very helpful for a similar problem, where I wanted to restrict RMI to localhost for security purposes.  However, I found that I also needed to restrict the port 1098 socket.  That can be done by supplying this same socket factory to the constructor of the remoted classes, e.g.
    public class RemoteStatistics extends UnicastRemoteObject
    {
        private RemoteStatistics() throws RemoteException
        {
            super(1098,
                  null,
                  RestrictableRMIRegistry.getInstance());
        }

Comment: Sorry, I'm a noob with SO comment markup and I'm struggling to get that code to format properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the [`java.rmi.server.hostname`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html) property to `127.0.0.1` when starting the registry (or any other Java process involved in your scheme).

Comment: Not a bad idea, but it won't affect the Registry, only other remote stubs exported from the JVMs where the property is set, because Registry stubs are constructed locally, not acquired remotely. A .policy file that restricts the SocketPermission 'accept' is another possibility.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. When I run `rmiregistry` with that set, it still opens up a port that's wide open. :–( I know how to fix, but it will take a little bit to write up as it requires code.

Comment: `java.rmi.server.hostname` doesn't control the listening port, it controls what is written into the stub. `LocateRegistry.getRegistry()` constructs a Registry stub locally from the host:port you give it, so the setting of `java.rmi.server.hostname` at the registry's JVM can't have any effect on that stub. To get the Registry, or any other remote object, to open a port bound to 127.0.0.1 it is necessary to specify an `RMIServerSocketFactory` that does so when exporting it.

Comment: @EJP Yes, was writing that up as a separate answer at that point…

Answer (score 0):

The good alternative is called web service over HTTP that is typically open for outbound connections.

The problem is with inbound connections. I believe that the "right" architecture is when processes deployed behind firewall are talking to each other through 3rd process - server that is installed somewhere where inbound HTTP connection is not restricted. So, 2 components that are behind firewall perform only outbound HTTP connection to the server.

Comment: I don't need to do any of that. All parts of the system are running on one machine, and need no external resources. The problem is that windows firewall blocks rmiregistry, which I was using for local IPC.